# Windows authentication log

Tags: windows, logging, domain

Windows domain.

Problem is in audit feature. I know how to enable audit in `Group policy`, but there is problem. One of our `domain admins` has killed host computer with hyper-v and we don't know who it were. Logon logs `group policy` standard, were on this computer and now destroyed.

As I suggest current problem is unsolvable, but for the future we need some sort of tools for it.

My first idea were `power shell` or `PHP` script which start on user logon and do insert in SQL, but if user login on other computer and from there will do `\\computer\c$` and kill there everything than script will not run.

Is there in `windows` or 3rd party software some sort of instrument which stores logs from computer to another place, `rsyslog` i.e or copies current computer logs to some server excluded from domain with only local users on it?

Any `good practices` appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Event Forwarding will meet basic needs.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/use-windows-event-forwarding-to-assist-in-intrusion-detection